# Converges of sin functions with fractions

Tags: calculus

$$\sum \frac{\sin(n)}{n^{3/2}}$$

What strategy would I use to test for convergence for this series?

Comment: Well $\sin(n)$ is bounded, and $\sum \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$ is a $p$-series. Maybe you can use this info to compare these two series using a test?

Answer (score 1):

Notice

$$ | \sin \alpha | \leq 1 $$

for all $\alpha$. Hence

$$ a_n = \frac{\sin (n) }{n^{3/2}} \leq \frac{1}{n^{3/2} } = b_n$$

Obviously, $\sum b_n$ converges. Now, by comparison test, $\sum a_n$ must converge.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to previous post, just noting that the comparison test says that your series converges absolutely, and if a series converges absolutely then it converges.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You can use the [Dirichlet's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test).